# Is there any Hadith describing the prophet wipe ing his neck in Wudu?

Tags: source-identification, wudu

Is there any authentic Hadith that describes the Prophet (May Allah's peace and blessings be upon HIm) as wipe ing his neck in wudu?

Answer (score 4):

**No**, there is no authentic Hadith regarding wiping the neck. It should not be wiped.

See relevant fatwa by Bin Baz [in Arabic](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/70120) or [in English](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/70120). In summary, there is a weak Hadith that Hanafi's followed, but it isn't authentic. A discussion of that Hadith and others can be found [here](http://www.alukah.net/Web/dbian/10813/29382/) (in Arabic). An additional reference is [here](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=22423) (in Arabic too).